# Role of frequency parameter in ts

Tags: r, time-series, prediction, forecasting, predict

How does the `ts()` function use its `frequency` parameter? What is the effect of assigning wrong values as `frequency`?

I am trying to use 1.5 years of website usage data to build a time series model so that I can forecast the usage for coming periods. I am using data at daily level. What should be the `frequency` here - 7 or 365 or 365.25?

Comment: The frequency is the seasonality component in a time series. If you have a daily level data set, you can set 365 as frequency, but you need to have at least 730 observation (two periods). Though there are some problems with it in R, see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65585/auto-arima-does-not-recognize-seasonal-pattern) for possible solution. A frequency of 7 is for weekly seasonality. If your data contains one, you should probably add it too, see [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/52462/arima-double-seasonality-with-dummy-in-r-error-xreg) for an example

Comment: @Braj, please let us know what you think about the answers given, e.g. if one is correct or at least helpful, or if answers could be improved with further clarifications.

Comment: @Maciej Baranowski: ts here is time series object in R.

Answer (score 2):

The `frequency` is "the" period at which seasonal cycles repeat. I use "the" in scare quotes since, of course, there are often multiple cycles in time series data. For instance, daily data often exhibit weekly patterns (a frequency of 7) and yearly patterns (a frequency of 365 or 365.25 - the difference often does not matter).

In your case, I would assume that weekly patterns dominate, so I would assign `frequency=7`. If your data exhibits additional patterns, e.g., holiday effects, you can use specialized methods accounting for multiple seasonalities, or work with dummy coding and a regression-based framework.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the `frequency` parameter is not a frequency that you can observe in the data of your time series. Instead, you have to specify the frequency at which samples of the time series were taken. In your case, this is simply 1 day, or `1`.

The value you give here will influence the results you get later when running analysis operations (examples are average requests per time unit or fourier transformation to get the (real) frequencies in the data). E.g. if you wanted to get all your results in the unit of hours instead of in days, you would pass `24` instead of `1` as `frequency`, because your data samples were taken in a frequency of 24 hours.

Comment: what you are saying and and what Stephan is saying above are sounding opposite to me. Can you please help me understand! This difference is the main cofusion that I am having!

Comment: In fact it is two different things that Stephan and me describe. Your question is about the parameter to some function and not about the general question what a frequency is. I think that I answered your question while Stephan describes generally what a frequency is.

Comment: What Stephan describes is one of the things that you might want to get out of your data when you process it. What I describes is important in the step before, when you create your data series object.