# What are the consequences of choosing different frequencies for ts objects?

Tags: r, time-series

To create a ts-object in R, one has to specify a data frame, a start date and the frequency of the time series.

When searching the internet (e.g. [Role of frequency parameter in ts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26713224/role-of-frequency-parameter-in-ts)), I get the impression that by choosing the frequency, one can emphasise whatever periodic pattern one believes is the most important in the data. However, I doubt that this is actually true. My impression is that it is solely used to compute the dates of the time series on-the-fly. E.g. when I set the start date “2015-08-01”, R automatically transforms it into a decimal date and I get something like 2015.58. If I now choose a frequency of 365 (or 365.25), R divides one unit by 365 and assigns this fraction to each day as one unit ahead, so the entry 366 days later is exactly 2016.58. However, if I choose frequency=7, the fraction assigned to each day is 1/7th, so the date assigned to the 8th day after my start date corresponds to a decimal number between 2016 and 2017. So the only choice for a data set with 365 entries per year is 365, isn’t it? And it is only used to actually create the time series?

Otherwise, if I choose the xts-class, an xts-object is built from a vector and a matrix where the vector has to be created in advance. So here there is no need to compute the date on-the-fly using a start date and a frequency and that is the reason why no frequency has to be assigned at all.

In both cases I can apply forecasting packages to either ts or xts objects (such as ARIMA, ets, stl, bats, bats etc) without specifying anything else so this shows that the frequency is actually not used for anything else. Or am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance for your comments!

Comment: This might be better researched over on https://stats.stackexchange.com/ as it doesn't really seem to have anything to do with specific R code.